# unable to load the angular js module getting angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, bootstrap-modal

initially i figured that it`s may be because of the ngRoute module so I have added the dependency as well even though getting the same error.as a beginner this is eating my head .... guys any help

index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Contact List Application</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"  ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <h1>Contact List for Members</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>contact</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
                    <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.number}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>

    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script  src="controllers/controller.js">

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
     .controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl($scope) {


        person1 = {
            name: 'tm',
            email: 'tm@gmail.com',
            number: '(111) 222-2222'
        };
        person2 = {
            name: 'dk',
            email: 'dik@gmail.com',
            number: '(111) 222-2223'
        };
        person3 = {
            name: 'hey',
            email: 'hey@gmail.com',
            number: '(111) 222-2224'
        };

        var contactlist = [person1, person2, person3];
        $scope.contactlist = contactlist;
    });
```

testing the code on online code compiler its working fine but when I am running this code in node server localhost its throwing the above error.

Comment: What is error in console. ?? Just F12

Comment: angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.3%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A179)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4920
    at p (angular.js:402)
    at g (angular.js:4880)
    at eb (angular.js:4802)
    at c (angular.js:1909)
    at Pc (angular.js:1930)
    at ue (angular.js:1815)
    at angular.js:33340
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3435)

Answer (score 0):

I Think this happens because you are using minified version of the angular. When you are using minified version you need to add the dependencies injected to controllers as separate string array like this

`.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function AppCtrl($scope) {`

This approach should be done for all the services/controllers and directives.

The reason is when your script is minified, dependency injector unable to identify which service is which. If you see your minify code then you might notice the dependency that you injected in not there.Instead of that, there are one or two characters that reference to relevant dependency.

so what angular does is in order to find which dependency is which they allow us to write the dependency as a string array. Then injector can easily identify the services

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
     .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function AppCtrl($scope) {


        person1 = {
            name: 'tm',
            email: 'tm@gmail.com',
            number: '(111) 222-2222'
        };
        person2 = {
            name: 'dk',
            email: 'dik@gmail.com',
            number: '(111) 222-2223'
        };
        person3 = {
            name: 'hey',
            email: 'hey@gmail.com',
            number: '(111) 222-2224'
        };

        var contactlist = [person1, person2, person3];
        $scope.contactlist = contactlist;
    }]);
```

Comment: i have tried your suggestion even though still the problem persist

Comment: can u create a demo